# How to Configure/Enable Request Router Helper for IIS 8.5

Tags: iis, iis-8.5, arr

We have a web filter/load balancer that directs traffic to our IIS 8.5 (Windows 2012 R2) servers.  The issue is that in the IIS logs, the IP address (c-ip field) is logged as the local address of our load balancer (a Sophos UTM, not Microsoft’s ARR) while we need to log the actual client’s source IP (which is provided in the “custom” `X-Forwarded-For` header).  I can’t use the “Advanced Logging” features of IIS to simply create another column as our log monitoring software can’t deal with this custom field, nor deal with the “_x” appended to the log file name.

Therefore, I have spent a number of hours trying to get Microsoft’s Request Router Helper to automatically convert the `X-Forwarded-For` field value to the `c-ip` field (which, I believe, it is supposed to do).  Based on the reference sites I’ve listed below, I’ve done the following:

1. Installed the requestrouterhelper_x64.msi from a ARR v3 installation on to our IIS 8.5 server
2. I verified I could see the file *(but did not change anything)* at: C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\schema\arr_helper_schema.xml
3. I do not see any additional modules or features in IIS Manager *(should I?)*
4. Viewed the log files *(after IISRESET and even a reboot)* and the c-ip value is still being recorded as 127.0.0.1, not the client's IP address

Are there any other things I need to do to enable/configure the Request Router Helper from ARR to automatically transpose the client IP into the c-ip field?

References:

[IIS7/8: Logging the real client IP in the IIS hit logs](https://blogs.iis.net/deanc/iis7-8-logging-the-real-client-ip-in-the-iis-hit-logs)

[Client-ip not logged on application server when using ARR **(original version for IIS 7)**](https://blogs.iis.net/anilr/client-ip-not-logged-on-content-server-when-using-arr)

[ARR Helper **(for IIS8 - see accepted answer)**](https://forums.iis.net/t/1214989.aspx?ARR%20Helper%20for%20IIS8%20)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After many hours, we found out how to enable this on IIS 8.5.  Here are the steps:

1. Download the 64-bit version of the tool from **[this site](https://blogs.iis.net/anilr/client-ip-not-logged-on-content-server-when-using-arr)**.  Do **NOT** install the version obtained by installing the ARR v3 Web Platform Installer *(this was the biggest issue with it not working)*.
2. Unzip and run the MSI from an admin command prompt
3. Open `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config` and check its module registration under the globalModules section (it should be as follows)

> < add name="ARRHelper" image="%ProgramFiles%\IIS\ARR Helper\requestRouterHelper.dll" />

4. In the same file, check or add the following entry in the section location `path="" / modules`

> < add name="ARRHelper" />

I hope this helps others that had this same frustration.

Comment: As an update for Windows Server 2016+ (IIS 10.0), you must TEMPORARILY change the registry key at HKLM > SOFTWARE > Microsoft > InetStp > MajorVersion from "a" to 9, then perform the install, then you can change it back to "a".

Comment: This is still the way to go with Windows Server 2022 on IIS 10.0. The registry key workaround outlined by @bigmac is required as well. Powershell:


$registryPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp"
$valueName = "MajorVersion"
$currentMajorVersion = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $registryPath -Name $valueName
Set-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $valueName -Value 9
Start-Process arr_helper_x64.msi -ArgumentList "/passive /norestart" -Wait 
Set-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $valueName -Value $currentMajorVersion

Answer (score 1):

Thank you bigmac. Your answer definitely helped. One thing I had to do in my environment to get it working:

1. Run the .MSI as admin via command prompt (as bigmac said). However, I noticed that after doing this the program didn't actually install (check programs in control panel).
2. Right click and install the .MSI a second time (not from command prompt).
3. Check to make sure the ApplicationHost.config was modified at time of install. This will confirm if install is successful.

   I tried several attempts and noticed that it would only work after doing these steps in this order. If you run the installer first (not as admin) it will install but not work.

Answer (score 0):

For those out there with IIS 10 with Windows 2019 the link provided by bigmac works.  Additionally, after much research and trial and error, I found that having custom fields in the logging stops ARR from logging the X-Forwarded-For header.  I had to remove the custom logging fields, then ARR started working correctly.